# Creating own snap images

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I see some similarities between Snap and Docker. I cant find on internet any guide how to create snap image, like image in Docker. How to create it?
I want to build snap with some old libs and old app that misbehave on new Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not a heavy Docker user, but Docker images typically include the OS plus an application, right? There's not an exact parallel in Snappy, so I'm not sure your question is clear. Are you wanting to generate a Snap that contains an application, or are you wanting to generate an image that you can flash to a device?

Comment: I want to generate snap with application to use on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read this articles

How to build snaps

- https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/

Examples on packaging snaps. It is useful for build desktop snaps. It includes examples using diferent languages, like google's GO.

- https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a snap, depending on what you're targeting you either want [this documentation (for IoT)](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/) or [this documentation (for desktop)](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/desktop/). Note that the process is the same, but the examples contained at the links will be more focused on one or the other.

Comment: Second link is not even documentation, is news article or something. But I try with first one.

Comment: Haha, scroll down to the "Get Started with Snapcraft" button or the "Jump to examples" link.

Comment: Nope man. "Assuming you have an app ready to package with a snapcraft.yaml file" this is not answer to question. I want to how build snaps from scratch. This article is far away from that.

Comment: Right underneath that sentence is a link: "Learn more about building apps." It's the first link I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned this explicitly so I will just say that to make snap packages you should use `snapcraft`. There's ample documentation and examples for various kinds of applications you can make.